# Updating a nested object in Redux via reduce?

Tags: reactjs, redux

When updating a nested object in Redux via reducer, how would I remove an object nested in an array? Say I wanted to remove name: 'stuffOne' object?

```
{
  myStuff: {
    myNestedStuff: {
      stuff: {
        label: 'stuff';
        stuffArray: [
          {
            name: 'stuffOne'
          },
          {
            name: 'stuffTwo'
          },
          {
            name: 'stuffThree'
          }
        ];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not matter how you change the nested object, you only need to shadow clone the root object eg:

```
myStuff.myNestedStuff.stuff.stuffArray = myStuff.myNestedStuff.stuff.stuffArray.filter (s => s.name !== 'stuffOne')

return {...myStuff}
```